# Blocks are invisible after hosting drupal7

Tags: drupal-7

I am facing with a problem in drupal7, I am new to drupal7 too. When I run my website in localhost everything fine, blocks and menu are visible. But after I host my website in GoDaddy, that blocks and menu are invisible, where they gone. I am also hoping someone can help me to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: What does it mean, that they are invisible? Need more information to help. 
Do you reach admin/structure/block page?
Could you put the menu in a block?
Have you selected the same theme as in localhost?

Comment: Invisible I mean is when I run that website in localhost, I can see search block in left side bar and home navigation menu bar. But after I have hosted that web site in GoDaddy.com, block in left side bar and navigation menu are disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin/structure/block page and assign the search block and the navigation menu to the left side bar.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime this problem occurs when version mismatch between GoDaddy supported drupal and your drupal.